# SQL group by remove column

Tags: sql, database

i have to list of test flights want to show the summary and total, of arrival departure and cargo, however i don't want to add the opdate in the group by but i need it to be in the select

```
SELECT Nat
    ,opdate
    ,SUM(Arrival) AS Arr
    ,SUM(Depart) AS Dep
    ,SUM(APAX) AS [Arr Pax]
    ,SUM(DPAX) AS [Dep Pax]
    ,SUM(ATRX) AS [Arr Trx]
    ,SUM(AFRT) AS [Arr Frt]
    ,SUM(DFRT) AS [Dep Frt]
FROM (
    SELECT ArrNatuFull AS Nat
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS opdate
        ,1 AS Arrival
        ,AR1PAX AS APAX
        ,AR1FRT AS AFRT
        ,AR1TRA AS ATRX
        ,0 AS Depart
        ,0 AS DPAX
        ,0 AS DFRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute1 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS opdate
        ,0 AS Expr1
        ,AR2PAX
        ,AR2FRT
        ,AR2TRA
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_7
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute2 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,AR3PAX
        ,AR3FRT
        ,AR3TRA
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_6
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute3 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,AR4PAX
        ,AR4FRT
        ,AR4TRA
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_5
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (Aroute4 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,1 AS Expr6
        ,DR1PAX
        ,DR1FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_4
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute1 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR2PAX
        ,DR2FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_3
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute2 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR3PAX
        ,DR3FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_2
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute3 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR4PAX
        ,DR4FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_1
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (Droute4 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)
    ) AS anything
GROUP BY Nat
    ,opdate
```

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, Ms SQL,????

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY )` . Assuming you are using *oracle*:

```
SELECT Nat
    ,opdate
    ,SUM(Arrival) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS Arr
    ,SUM(Depart) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS Dep
    ,SUM(APAX) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS [Arr Pax]
    ,SUM(DPAX) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS [Dep Pax]
    ,SUM(ATRX) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS [Arr Trx]
    ,SUM(AFRT) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS [Arr Frt]
    ,SUM(DFRT) OVER (PARTITION BY Nat) AS [Dep Frt]
FROM (
    SELECT ArrNatuFull AS Nat
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS opdate
        ,1 AS Arrival
        ,AR1PAX AS APAX
        ,AR1FRT AS AFRT
        ,AR1TRA AS ATRX
        ,0 AS Depart
        ,0 AS DPAX
        ,0 AS DFRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute1 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS opdate
        ,0 AS Expr1
        ,AR2PAX
        ,AR2FRT
        ,AR2TRA
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_7
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute2 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,AR3PAX
        ,AR3FRT
        ,AR3TRA
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_6
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (ARoute3 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ArrNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATA) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,AR4PAX
        ,AR4FRT
        ,AR4TRA
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_5
    WHERE (ATA > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATA < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (Aroute4 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (ArrNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (ArrStOk <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,1 AS Expr6
        ,DR1PAX
        ,DR1FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_4
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute1 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR2PAX
        ,DR2FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_3
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute2 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR3PAX
        ,DR3FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_2
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (DRoute3 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DepNatuFull
        ,CONVERT(DATE, ATD) AS Expr1
        ,0 AS Expr2
        ,0 AS Expr3
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,0 AS Expr5
        ,0 AS Expr6
        ,DR4PAX
        ,DR4FRT
    FROM daily.dbo.Daily AS Daily_1
    WHERE (ATD > '2009-12-31 00:00')
        AND (ATD < '2015-08-01 23:59')
        AND (Droute4 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (DepNatuFull <> 'NON')
        AND (DepStOK <> 0)
    ) AS anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an attribute in the SELECT clause and not in the GROUP BY is only possible if you apply an aggregate function (MIN, MAX, etc) on the attributes. What I do not understand is, why you do not what it in GROUP BY clause? If you know, that each group that is formed by `Nat` alone result in equal values of `opdate`, adding `opdate` to GROUP BY does not alter the result. If the values of `opdate` are not equal with group that are formed by `Nat` alone, what is the semantic (if you do no apply an aggregate function) of your result?